# Bridging edge loops along a curve in geonodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, edges

Here's the rundown, I have created a curve and instanced some edge loops that have the same amount of vertices. What I need to do is to bridge each loop with the next in the curve.

I don't know if it's possible to also add cuts in the bridges to interpolate between loops but I'm also aiming for that.

[image: My current situation]

I've found a post on bridging edge loops but it didn't work in my case
([Is there a way to Bridge Edge Loops with Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227730/is-there-a-way-to-bridge-edge-loops-with-geometry-nodes))

Comment: *"it didn't work for my case"* - why?

Comment: Mesh just wasn't appearing, maybe I made a mistake along the way but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: You convert curve to points, then spawn `curveProfiles` there, so you want to connect resulting curves, creating a (heavily deformed) torus?

Comment: Try to check "loft" topic, like here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278462/create-mesh-from-four-curves-loft/278476#278476 ... I'm not sure how it works for closed  profiles.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Correct

Answer (score 2):

Given your specific assumptions, especially "the same amount of vertices", the solution seems simple: we already establish the way you want to loft is to create a torus. More specifically, each curve ("profile") seen on your screenshot should become a small loop of the torus (assuming default horizontal orientation of the torus, that would be a vertical loop). Once you spawn the torus, adjust vertex positions by mapping them to the actual positions coming from your setup. In this case the mapping is the simplest possible, just one-to-one:

[image]

[image]