# How to perform a "bridge edge loops" on two geometries using nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to bridge two edge loops using Geometry Nodes under Blender 3.5.1
The edge loops are not similar in shape (for instance square vs. circle)

I found [This post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227730/is-there-a-way-to-bridge-edge-loops-with-geometry-nodes), however I'm not sure it applies to my case as the bridging is done by scaling and translating the edges whereas in my case it's not possible as they are different shapes.

What I'm starting with (the edges loops are initially separate objects that I joined using nodes):

[image]

What I would like to get (image obtained by applying the current nodes and manually using the bridge tool):

[image]

I cannot simply compute the convex hull as the edge loops can be concave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends a lot on what you really want to do in the end and what your shapes are like, but starting with two simple shapes you could solve this as follows:

[image]

Here I use as a starting point the shape that consists of several vertices or is more complex (in this case the circle).

I extrude it and move the extruded points to the nearest points of the simpler shape.

I then combine the two meshes to form a whole.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.5+)*</sub>

Answer (score 4):

It seems in your case simply joining and using *Convex Hull* node will work:

[image]